# build login using Django and Angular error credential not provided

Tags: django, angular

i'm try to build a basic login app using Django backend and Angular like fronted, when i use the login component and write the correct credential username and password in the form, then redirect to another component sendme this error,

Important: the login give me the token but then after the login and redirect to another component ,error

[error Authentication credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vx5I.png)
[image]

[login form with correct credentials username password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwGNO.png)
[image]
settings .py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
 'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated', 'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
    ),

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
       'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ],
      'NON_FIELD_ERRORS_KEY': 'global',
}
```

url .py

```
        path('auth/login/', obtain_jwt_token),
    path('auth/refresh-token/', refresh_jwt_token),
```

login component.ts and .html

```
constructor(
  private authService: AuthService,
  private router: Router,
) { }
login(username: string, password: string) {
  this.authService.login(username, password).subscribe(
    success => this.router.navigate(['categorias']),
    error =>         alert('Error al Conectar Datos ')
  );
}


<input class="form-control form-control-sm" #username type='text' placeholder='username'>
<input class="form-control form-control-sm" #password type='password' placeholder='password'>
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="login(username.value, password.value)">login</button>
```

Comment: Do you send the token to the protected endpoint that you want to access? I don't see it in the code that you attached.

Comment: do you mean the  auth in fronted? @CatalinHoha ty por coment

Comment: @CatalinHoha this is my git https://github.com/jimrooto/Laboratorio1